# Converting .pgm to .png in Python

Tags: python

**Problem:**
I want to import all ".pgm" files from several folders and store them as ".png".

For this I use the following lines of code:

```
from glob import glob

files=glob('yaleB*/*.pgm')
print 'number of files is',len(files)
count=0
for f in files:
    new_f=f[:-3]+'png'
    !convert $f $new_f
    count += 1
    if count % 100==0:
        print count,f,new_f
```

Unfortunately, I always get this error: `"command not found: convert"`

Is there a simple fix for this?
My assumption is, that this is an "old" command (Jupyter Notebook where I took this code from is from 2014..)

Answer (score 4):

you can try using os and pillow

```
import os
from PIL import Image

for file in os.listdir():
    filename, extension  = os.path.splitext(file)
    if extension == ".pgm":
        new_file = "{}.png".format(filename)
        with Image.open(file) as im:
            im.save(new_file)
```

Comment: thanks! as mentioned above. I will skip the step changing the files.

Answer (score 3):

The exclamation mark (`!`) means it is an external command, and `convert` is part of the **ImageMagick** package.

So you would need to install **ImageMagick** for it to work. Note that if you install v7 or newer, the command would become:

```
!magick INPUT.PGM OUTPUT.PNG
```

---

However, if you want to convert all PGM files in the current directory to PNG files, you don't even need a loop, you can do them all in one go with:

```
magick mogrify -format png *.pgm
```

---

Yet more caveats... there is no real need from a Python point of view to convert PGM files to PNG, since **OpenCV**, **PIL/Pillow**, **wand** and **scikit-image** can all read PGM files anyway. So can **GIMP**, **feh**, **eog**, **Photoshop**.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment! I was the assumption that I have to change the files. If possible I'll skip that and work with the .pgm type.